# Ubuntu 18.04 Hangs/Freezes on LENOVO ideapad 330

Tags: lenovo, freeze, crash

I bought a new laptop, with the following specifications:

```
-LENOVO ideapad 330-15ICH
-Processor: Intel Core i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz 2.30GHz
-RAM Installed: 8 GB (7.88 GB usable)
-Graph: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
-Storage: 1 SSD (128 GB) + 1 HDD (1TB)
-Completely new computer. Windows 10 working perfectly fine
```

I performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 through an USB, no problems while doing it. I installed it alongside Windows 10, with the following partitions:

```
-Root, ~40 GB, in the SSD
-SWAP, ~8 GB, in the SSD (where Windows 10 is also installed).
-/home, ~700 GB, installed in an 1TB HDD
-A FAT32 partition in the 1TB HDD to share files between Windows and Linux.
```

Symptoms:

```
-At login screen, everything seems to work smoothly.
-However, right after logging in, touchpad seems not to work.
-Keyboard works briefly, however it stops working.
-The above issues seem to occur because system is hanging
 intermitently (until it finally freezes, after 1 or 2 minutes).
```

Last time it crashed, a window popped up, with the message "Ubuntu 18.04 has experienced an internal error" (which I was not able to fully read because the system freezed again):

```
-Package: linux-image-4.15.0-43.generic 4.15.0-43.46
-ProblemType: KernelOops
-Type: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [kworker/...(could not read)
-Alsainfo
-Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to b...(same as before)
-ApportVersion: 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.2
-Architecture: ...(could not see the rest of the window)
```

A co-worker told me to run a memory test on the computer, but when the GRUB is shown, the option for "memtest" does not appear. However, in the last login that I did, I opened a terminal just as soon as I logged into the system, and by keeping hitting buttons/commands, the computer did not crash, so I run "free -h", just to see that the memory was almost unused (RAM as well as SWAP).

However, I noticed that, while the system did not crash, the laptop temperature rised really fast, when it should not be like that, since I was doing absolutely nothing on it.

I tried to run Ubuntu with the only previous Kernel installed  (4.15.0.29) but I obtained the same results as before.

I'm almost sure this is a drivers+kernel problem, but I do not know what to do to solve this. And I need to solve it sooner than later, because I work with Linux and I use my laptop to work (I would remove Windows, but then I would lose the warranty in case something happens with the computer...). I read on other posts about people having problems with the touchpad. It might be related, but the problem is different.

ADD: Last boot, it worked without problems, and I did nothing different. Even managed to install a couple of things. But when I tried to reboot it, the system freezed. And when I booted it again, and it freezes again. I do not understand anything...

ADD+1: I booted Ubuntu again, through recovery mode of the main kernel, and checked the System Summary. Everything seemed fine, so I resumed normal mode. After logging in, everything worked fine. Even I turned off the laptop via terminal with "poweroff", and it worked. This does not make sense to me. I have to stress that the temperature is abnormally high

ADD+2: Boot normally again, internal error again, no working touchpad. After seeing the result of "top" (the following three are root processes):

```
-apport-gtk is using 200% CPU
-kworker/5:2 is using 100% CPU
-kworker/0:2 is using 100% CPU
```

Could someone explain what is going on?